# optimize a read-only sql server database: new tricks with 2012?

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

For a new customer we created a read-only database with all his old data. This database will be about 80Gigs but very simply structured.

On my research I found this: [tips for optimizing a read-only sql database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1876586/5089204)

What I found there is exactly the answer I expected with my SQL Server 2008 experience... I just want to ask, if there are new approaches, hints, tricks with SQL 2012.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this topic as finished I want to post the final solution:

"Normal" settings, DB on a SSD-Drive in the local hardware.

Works fast and reliable..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read more about

> Columnstore Indexes

Maybe the following article can help:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Although they are claimed to speed up things up to 10x (by Microsoft) they come with some limitations such as:
[...] A table with a columnstore index cannot be updated [...] (although this is not entirely true as you can circumvent this problem with partitions).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088%28v=sql.110%29.aspx#Restrictions

Comment: Thank you very much for this interesting hint. In my scenario (search for a person via some parameters and pick out detail data) it won't help probably, but anyway this could be a very powerfull step in the direction of NoSQL-DBs.